# tabbedPane selectionChangeListener not invoking method on tab selection

Tags: openfaces

I am having some problems getting the method specified in selectionChangeListener invoked on tab change.

The loadingMode is default, ajaxLazy, which means it should be called the first time a tab is selected. The tabbedPane is wrapped in

The el expression looks like:

```
selectionChangeListener="#{pageController.tabSelected}"
```

The method signature of the method binding is:

```
@Component("pageController") // Using spring for bean management
@Scope("request)"
public class PageController {

  public void tabSelected(SelectionChangeEvent e)
}
```

It is not throwing any exceptions so it is not even trying to resolve the method binding.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<o:tabbedPane loadingMode="server" rendered="true" selectionChangeListener="#{yourBeanName.listenerMethod}">
...
</o:tabbedPane>
```

As you can see I`m using server as loading mode. That way the listener method will be invoked each time a tab is clicked. If you use client as loading mode, the tab click event will not be picked up by the server.

For more info you can view the [documentation for tabbedPane](http://openfaces.org/documentation/developersGuide/tabbedpane.html)